# API Architecture - Business logic tightly coupled to routes?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, keystonejs

To speed up development for my next Node-API I was looking for a suitable Framework. In the past I was building my APIs with express only.

One Design pattern I always found useful is to completely seperate the business logic from route-handling in services. Those services only accept the required information (like a user id or data) and return a promise resolving the result of the operation.

This way it is easy to reuse these services in other routes, to combine them, test them, or call them based on schedules or other events - totally independent from endpoint-calls. Routing and Middleware take care of access-controll, error-handling and respondig.

Looking at the documentations of those frameworks (sailsjs, keystonejs, ...) I mostly see the business-logic tightly coupled to individual routes, directly accepting request objects and handling the responses. Only as an afterthought it seems there is sometimes offered a way to extract "often used code" into helper functions.

Am I missing something? How come this pattern seems to be the standard of API design? Is this a best practice for a reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might have to do with Node.js services being smaller in size. If you're coming from an enterprise background, you're well aware mixing business-logic with controller code doesn't fly in the long run. Perhaps small projects can get away with defying that, but once the size increases, you can't avoid the laws of physics. It's best to separate concerns and keep the codebase maintainable.

I'd also add that below services, it's good to have a separate layer that handles talking to outside process boundaries. That way, you can test business logic in isolation by providing appropriate test doubles for integrations. Here's a longer explanation of how it would work in a Node project: [Organize Node.js API project using 3-layer architecture](https://bytearcher.com/articles/node-project-structure/).